# Repository of sequence diagrams for design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Is there a good repository of design pattern sequence diagrams? Most repositories of design patterns I know ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), [sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)) have only class diagrams, and many times this is not enough to understand what the pattern really does and how it should be implemented, and I think that adding sequence diagrams to the description of the pattern could fill the needed blank, but have not seen this done. So, have you seen such repository?

Comment: I know this is old, but I started an UML astah project with some diagrams. Here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6nf9j2c34w6r5l/sequence_diagrams.asta

Answer (score 1):

Here are some patterns with seq. diagrams [gof patterns](http://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/design-patterns-in-sequence-diagrams).

Moreover there is a book mentioned o this site "GoF Design Patterns - With Examples Using Java and UML2". Hope you will find some samples there.